# Proof of continuity of a map from product of two spaces to $\mathbb R^n.$

Tags: differential-geometry, implicit-function-theorem, smooth-functions, inverse-function-theorem

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$  Given , $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^{m+n}$ and $f : U \to \mathbb R^n$ be a $C^1$ map ,then show that the map $F : (p,v) (\in U ×\mathbb R^{m+n}) \mapsto Df_p (v) (\in \mathbb R^n)$
is continuous .

$\mathbf {My \ approach}:$  Actually, taking a nbhd  $V$ of some point $Df_p (v)$ for some $p,v$ in $U$ and $\mathbb R^{m+n})$ resp. ,then it's getting difficult for me to think of nbhd $N$  around $(p,v)$ such that $F(N)$ is contained in $V.$

I am trying to use inverse function theorem, but there was a hypothesis that at some point $a$,$Df_a$ needs to be an isomorphism .

If $Df_p$ is onto for some $p \in U$, then $f$ locally ''looks like a'' a projection map.

Is this question correct?
If it is, then a small hint is appreciated .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What means *nbhd*???

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I think it stands for *neighborhood*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

For $r,s \in \mathbb N$, let $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^{r}, \mathbb R^s)$ be the linear space of linear maps from $\mathbb R^r$ to $\mathbb R^s$.

The map

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
G : & \mathcal L(\mathbb R^{m+n}, \mathbb R^n) \times \mathbb R^{m+n} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R^n \\
    & (U,v) & \longmapsto & U(v) \end{array}$$ is a bilinear map defined on a finite dimensional linear space. It is therefore continuous (and even smooth).

As $f$ is supposed to be $\mathcal C^1$ and

$$F(x,v) = G(f^\prime(x),v)$$ we get that $F$ is continuous as a composition of continuous maps.